# How to route VPN traffic through a separate internet connection with a SonicWALL firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, sonicwall

We have a depot quite some distance from the exchange, the expensive internet connection is only getting 2/1Mb. This causes constant drops as soon as someone downloads anything. We have now got a 4G (Mobile internet) box set up which is getting 35/20Mb, making the internet actually usable.

We now need to route the VPN traffic through the old connection, but allowing all other traffic to use the 4G box.

I haven't been able to find much information on what needs to be changed on the configuration for this to work.

Many thanks.

EDIT: Not possible with the TZ-180 due to only 1 wan port.

Comment: I'm assuming this depends on the device. I'm getting the model now.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specific equipment I cannot provide concise instructions.

You can configure your sonicwall to use 1 IP for the default gateway and a separate IP for your VPN connections.

You also should implement QOS on your network
http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/216/ui2/29/config/qos.html
If you tag and prioritize your traffic you can set critical traffic to make sure it is not starved for bandwidth, in this case your VPN.  You can guarantee bandwidth to the VPN and allow excess to other protocols.

Comment: Turned out the equipment doesn't support this. But thanks anyway.